# Filtering firebase forEach list using an array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently trying to create some filter buttons, that would filter a list fetched from firebase.

The current foreach looks like this:

```
                    ForEach((session.jobs)
                            .filter({ "\($0)".contains(searchText) || searchText.isEmpty })
                            //.filter({ "\($0)".contains(searchText2) || searchText2.isEmpty })
                ) { job in
                    
                    JobCardTemplate(job: job, session: self.session)
                }
```

The Jobs model:

```
struct JobData: Identifiable {
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var creator : String?
var title : String?
var company : String?
var city: String?
var salary : String?
var key : String?
var logo : String?
var category : String?
var created : String?
}
```

The filter button:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(session.categories.indices) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    // What to perform
                    self.session.categories[index].selected.toggle()
                    if(session.categories[index].selected == true){
                        self.selected.append(session.categories[index].title!)
                    } else{
                        if let index2 = selected.firstIndex(of: (session.categories[index].title!)) {
                            selected.remove(at: index2)
                        }
                    }
                    print(selected)
                }) {
                    
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: (session.categories[index].icon!))
                                .foregroundColor(session.categories[index].selected ? Color.white : Color.black)
                            Text("\(session.categories[index].title!)")
                                .foregroundColor(session.categories[index].selected ? Color.white : Color.black)
                        }
                    }
                .padding(.all, 8)
                .background(session.categories[index].selected ? Color.black : Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(session.categories[index].selected ? Color.black : Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
                )
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

I also have a search bar, but i need it to work either way even if the filter is selected or not. I've tried filtering from array, but i get an error saying that it doesnt support String and it need String characters.

Maybe someone tried doing something similar?

Answer (score 0):

The filter inside your `ForEach` is wrong. Write it like this:

```
ForEach(session.jobs.filter { $0.title.contains(searchText) || $0.company.contains(searchText) || $0.creator.contains(searchText) }) { job in
```

Filter on the properties inside the job object like I did there.

Comment: the filter u provided use the search bar, which is working for me. I have an array that is being appended by pressing the filter buttons. But the problem is, that if i want to use the values from the array as a search term, it doesn't work.
***Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')***